# Angular - TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Tags: angular, primeng

I have problem with binary, even if add brackets to it.

I'm using primeNG library.

**In HTML file I wrote this code:**

```
<div class="products-page">
    <div class="p-grid">
      <div class="p-col-3" *ngIf="!isCategoryPage">
        <h4>Categories</h4>
        <div class="p-field-checkbox" *ngFor="let category of categories">
          <p-checkbox
            [(ngModel)]="category.checked"
            binary="true"
            [inputId]="category.id"
            (onChange)="categoryFilter()"
          ></p-checkbox>
          <label for="{{ category.id }}">{{ category.name }}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div [ngClass]="{ 'p-col-9': !isCategoryPage, 'p-col-12': isCategoryPage }">
        <div class="p-grid" *ngIf="products">
          <div
            [ngClass]="{ 'p-col-4': !isCategoryPage, 'p-col-3': isCategoryPage }"
            *ngFor="let product of products"
          >
            <products-product-item [product]="product"></products-product-item>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

,,,,

**In ts file:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product, Category } from '@bluebits/products';
import { ProductsService } from '../../services/products.service';
import { CategoriesService } from '../../services/categories.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'products-list',
  templateUrl: './products-list.component.html'
})
export class ProductsListComponent implements OnInit {

  products: Product[] = [];
  categories: Category[] = [];
  isCategoryPage: boolean;

  constructor(
    private prodService: ProductsService,
    private catService: CategoriesService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      params.categoryid ? this._getProducts([params.categoryid]) : this._getProducts();
      params.categoryid ? (this.isCategoryPage = true) : (this.isCategoryPage = false);
    });
    this._getCategories();
  }

  private _getProducts(categoriesFilter?: string[]) {
    this.prodService.getProducts(categoriesFilter).subscribe((resProducts) => {
      this.products = resProducts;
    });
  }

  private _getCategories() {
    this.catService.getCategories().subscribe(
      (resCats) => {
        this.categories = resCats;
      }
    )
  }

  categoryFilter() {
    const selectedCategories = this.categories
      .filter((category) => category.checked)
      .map((category) => category.id);

    this._getProducts(selectedCategories);
  }
}
```

**In module file:**

I Import this module

```
import { CheckboxModule } from 'primeng/checkbox';
```

I got this error:

> error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
>
> binary="true"

**How can I fix it?**

Comment: [enter image description here](https://imgur.com/TmPQIOz)

Comment: Avoid posting code screenshots, use `codeblocks` instead so people can copy and paste your code, allowing to reproduce your problems more easily.

Answer (score 35):

When you do `binary="true"`, you're assigning a string to a property that expects a boolean. To pass the `true` boolean value rather than the `"true"` string you'll have to use the brackets syntax:

```html
<p-checkbox [binary]="true" [(ngModel)]="checked"></p-checkbox>
```

Comment: I tried to add brackets but I got the same result.

Comment: The problem does not solve MR.Allan.                                                                                I have another kind of these problems.                                                               TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
<p-badge **[value]="cartCount"** severity="danger"></p-badge>

Comment: In this case it's the other way around - you're assigning a number (`cartCount`) to a property that expectes a string (`value`). Just cast `cartCount` to string before assigning and you'll be fine.

Comment: facing the same issue and your solution does not work for me as well.

Comment: Try opening a new thread, providing a reproducible example and someone will be able to help.

Comment: Yes this fixed it. Prime NG need to update their docs.

Answer (score 10):

The Angular CDK has a [useful concept](https://material.angular.io/cdk/coercion/overview) of declaring your `@Input()`s as `BooleanInput` instead of `boolean`. This allows `myProp="true"` to work in addition to `[myProp]=true`.

The `coerceBooleanProperty` function ensures that the input value is a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `[value]="true"` attribute:

```html
<p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="category.checked" [binary]="true" [value]="true"></p-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify and add some references:

The `binary` attribute is [a boolean](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/b50f3d73fc6ac950c38c760941819ea47bbff71c/src/app/components/checkbox/checkbox.ts#L45) property of the `p-checkbox`. Your angular template is attempting to set (*bind*) it to `true` (it might not seem evident at first glance that the attribute assignment binds a property, but as the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#binding-to-a-property) suggest: "*In most cases, the target name is the name of a property, **even when it appears to be the name of an attribute**.*").

The same [doc](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#binding-to-a-property) proceeds to state:

> The brackets, [], cause Angular to evaluate the right-hand side of the
> assignment as a dynamic expression. Without the brackets, Angular
> treats the right-hand side as a string literal and sets the property
> to that static value.

I.E., w/o the brackets, 'binary' is assigned the 'true' string literal, which is then flagged as an assignment error by typescript. `[binary]='true'` triggers an evaluation of 'true' to the boolean value.

BTW, you might conclude that you can workaround the issue by using interpolation (`binary="{{true}}"`). Indeed the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#property-binding-and-interpolation) support this notion, stating that "*Often interpolation and property binding can achieve the same results.*". It does however qualify that by noting that "*when setting an element property to a non-string data value, you must use property binding*".